# How to perform unittest for floating point outputs? - python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, floating-point, precision

Let's say I am writing a unit test for a function that returns a floating point number, I can do it as such in full precision as per my machine:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> def div(x,y): return x/float(y)
... 
>>>
>>> class Testdiv(unittest.TestCase):
...     def testdiv(self):
...             assert div(1,9) == 0.1111111111111111
... 
>>> unittest.main()
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Will the same full floating point precision be the same across OS/distro/machine?

I could try to round off and do a unit test as such:

```
>>> class Testdiv(unittest.TestCase):
...     def testdiv(self):
...             assert round(div(1,9),4) == 0.1111
... 
>>>
```

I could also do an assert with `log(output)` but to keep to a fix decimal precision, I would still need to do rounding or truncating.

But what other way should one pythonically deal with unittesting for floating point output?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The precision of `float` in Python is dependent on the underlying C representation. From [*Tutorial/Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations, 15.1*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error):

> Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point
> arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754
> “double precision”.

---

As for testing, a better idea is to use existing functionality, e.g. [`TestCase.assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual):

> ***assertAlmostEqual(first, second, places=7, msg=None, delta=None)***

> Test that *first* and *second* are approximately (or not approximately)
> equal by computing the difference, rounding to the given number of
> decimal *places* (default 7), and comparing to zero. If *delta* is supplied instead of *places* then the difference between *first* and *second* must be less or equal to (or greater than) *delta*.

Example:

```
import unittest

def div(x, y): return x / float(y)

class Testdiv(unittest.TestCase):
    def testdiv(self):
        self.assertAlmostEqual(div(1, 9), 0.1111111111111111)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(div(1, 9), 0.1111, places=4)

unittest.main() # OK
```

If you prefer to stick to `assert` statement, you could use the [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) (Python 3.5+):

```
import unittest, math

def div(x, y): return x / float(y)

class Testdiv(unittest.TestCase):
    def testdiv(self):
        assert math.isclose(div(1, 9), 0.1111111111111111)

unittest.main() # OK
```

The default relative tolerance of `math.close` is 1e-09, *"which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits."*. For more information about `math.close` see [PEP 485](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485).

Comment: How to unit test two lists with floating values?

Answer (score 21):

The `unittest.TestCase` class has specific methods for comparing floats: [`assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) and [`assertNotAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNotAlmostEqual). To quote the documentation:

> **assertAlmostEqual**(*first, second, places=7, msg=None, delta=None*)
>   **assertNotAlmostEqual**(*first, second, places=7, msg=None, delta=None*)
>
> Test that *first* and *second* are approximately (or not approximately)
>   equal by computing the difference, rounding to the given number of
>   decimal *places* (default 7), and comparing to zero. Note that these
>   methods round the values to the given number of *decimal places* (i.e.
>   like the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function) and not *significant digits*.
>
> If *delta* is supplied instead of *places* then the difference between
>   *first* and *second* must be less or equal to (or greater than) *delta*.

Thus, you could test the function like this:

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(div(1, 9), 0.1111111111111111)  # round(a-b, 7) == 0
self.assertAlmostEqual(div(1, 9), 0.1111, 4)           # round(a-b, 4) == 0
```

On a side note, unless you use `pytest` as a tests runner, you should prefer the `TestCase.assert*` methods to bare `assert` statements, as the test failure messages produced by the methods are generally much more informative.