# Identical (but reordered) lists return different scipy.stats.linregress outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, linear-regression

I am unsure why using `scipy.stats.linregress` I get different outputs for the same inputs in different orders.

```py
>>> stats.linregress(y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],x=[1, 20, 300, 4000, 50000])
LinregressResult(slope=5.3988289118152344e-05, intercept=2.413460429362569, rvalue=0.749239235887126, pvalue=0.14493472207541896, stderr=2.755324936068815e-05)
>>> stats.linregress(y=[5, 3, 1, 4, 2],x=[50000, 300, 1, 4000, 20])
LinregressResult(slope=5.3988289118152324e-05, intercept=2.413460429362569, rvalue=0.7492392358871259, pvalue=0.14493472207541908, stderr=2.755324936068815e-05)
```

I know these value differences are near negligible practically, but when writing tests, this is becoming a bit of a burden. Is there a reason why this might be happening? Is there a way around it (without rounding up or truncating the actual output)?

Comment: Since the precision of the results is really not significant, why not round it and keep only few significant digits?

Comment: @MikeSperry Hmm, you could technically say I'm interested in precision, I'm more interested in why these returned values aren't identical instead of "[returning] too many decimals"

Comment: @deeboeh I would ?? the source for the why. It's most likely that the numbers hit the operations in a different order, so precision errors accumulate differently. To solve it for testing, I think comparing to appropriate levels of precision is the best solution.  Less desirable, but you could also consider sorting the input before feeding it to this function.

Comment: This is normal floating point imprecision.  Finite precision floating point addition is not associative--the order of calculation affects the result.  Compare, for example, `0.1 + 0.3 + 0.4` and `0.4 + 0.3 + 0.1`.  I get `0.8` and `0.7999999999999999`, respectively.   You say *"but when writing tests, this is becoming a bit of a burden."*  For floating point calculations, one generally tests for the values being sufficiently close rather than being exactly equal.  `numpy` has the function [`allclose`](https://www.numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for this.

Comment: I'm unable to mark this one a duplicate again, but with clarification from the author, it sounds like this is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199548/how-to-perform-unittest-for-floating-point-outputs-python

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, I'm kinda self teaching so knowing this standard is really helpful!