# How to test if a function calls range in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, range

I'm a Python instructor and I wanted to give my students a task: write a function that computes the average of a list using a for loop and the range object.

I wanted to run a test on their function to see whether it actually uses the range object. How can I do that?

It should be something like this:

```
def avg(L):
    Pass

def test_range(avg):
    ...
```

If `avg` contains `range`, then `test_range` should return `True`.

I tried solutions that utilize `func_code`, but apparantly `range` doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#) module to wrap around the `range` function from the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module, and then let your test assert that the wrapped `range` was indeed called.

For example, using Python's [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) framework for writing the test:

```
import builtins
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

# I don't know what L is supposed to be, and I know that there 
# are better ways to compute average of a list, but the code
# for calculating the average is not important for this question.
def avg(L):
    total = 0
    for index in range(len(L)):
        total += L[index]
    return total / len(L)

class TestAverage(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_avg(self):
        with patch("builtins.range", wraps=builtins.range) as wrapped_patch:
            expected = 47
            actual = avg([1,49,91])
            self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
        wrapped_patch.assert_called()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v main.py
test_avg (main.TestAverage) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

It uses `unittest.mock`'s [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) targetting the `builtins.range` function. Normally, `patch` is used in tests to replace the behavior and/or return value of the target, but in this case, you can pass `wraps=builtins.range` (which gets passed to the underlying [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) object), which means "*I just want to spy on the call, but not modify its behavior*":

> *wraps*: Item for the mock object to wrap. If *wraps* is not `None` then calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the real result).

By wrapping it in a `Mock` object, you can use any of `Mock`'s assert functions to check calls to `range`, like [`assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) which checks whether the target was called at least once. You can be more specific by asserting the number of times `range` was called:

```
self.assertTrue(wrapped_patch.call_count == 1)
```

The assertion would fail if it wasn't called at all:

```
# Here, `range` wasn't used at all.
def avg(L):
    return sum(L) / len(L)

class TestAverage(unittest.TestCase):
    # same as the code above
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v main.py
test_avg (main.TestAverage) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_avg (main.TestAverage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 15, in test_avg
    wrapped_patch.assert_called()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 888, in assert_called
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'range' to have been called.
```

The most important thing to note when using `patch`, is to know exactly [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). In this case, you can check the docs or use `__module__` to know `range`'s module:

```
>>> range
<class 'range'>
>>> range.__module__
'builtins'
```

But the test is a bit naive, because it can still pass even though `avg` didn't really use `range`:

```
def avg(L):
    range(len(L))  # Called but really unused. Sneaky!
    return sum(L) / len(L)

class TestAverage(unittest.TestCase):
    # same as the code above
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v main.py
test_avg (main.TestAverage) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

A slightly confusing workaround would be a test that "breaks" `range` such that, if the function was *really* using `range`, then it wouldn't work anymore:

```
def avg(L):
    range(len(L))  # Called but really unused. Sneaky!
    return sum(L) / len(L)

class TestAverage(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_avg(self):
        # same as above

    def test_avg_is_really_using_range(self):
        L = [10,20,90]
        # Is it returning the correct result?
        self.assertEqual(avg(L), 40)

        # OK, but did it really use `range`?
        # Let's try breaking `range` so it always yields 0,
        # so we expect the return value to be *different*
        with patch("builtins.range", return_value=[0,0,0]):
            self.assertNotEqual(avg(L), 40)
```

So, if `avg` was sneakily calling but not really using `range`, then `test_avg_is_really_using_range` would now fail because `avg` still yields the correct value even with a broken `range`:

```
$ python -m unittest -v main.py
test_avg (main.TestAverage) ... ok
test_avg_really_using_range (main.TestAverage) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_avg_really_using_range (main.TestAverage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 19, in test_avg_really_using_range
    self.assertNotEqual(avg(L), 40)
AssertionError: 40.0 == 40
```

Lastly, as a side note, I'm using `assertEqual` here in all the example because the test for the return value is not the focus, but do read up on proper ways to assert possible float values, ex. [How to perform unittest for floating point outputs? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33199548/2745495)